# Why aren't jest tests passed while using react fragments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm having an issue while testing my **react** app with **jest**.

The problem is that when i use react fragments in a component which i want to test , Jest throws an error .
for example :

```
<>
  My Component
</>
```

But when i use <**div**> instead of **<>** the tests get passed! But it will ruin the component's shape.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: error : TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$fuwzrglepr' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution was to replace empty tags with `<React.Fragment/>`. Basically empty tags are syntactic sugars to facilitate the use of fragments but some tools didn't know them until the most recent updates.

Answer (score 1):

The empty tags `<></>` don't replace an actual DOM element like a `<div />`. It's just syntactic sugar to facilitate the use of multiple components without wrapping them inside a single parent element in JSX.

You either need to adapt your tests to not access the first `<div />` of your tested component or keep the DOM hierarchy as it is without replacing the div's with empty tags.

That being said, JSX fragments shorthand is only available in Babel v7.0.0-beta.31 and above, as shown in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#babel). If you're already on Babel v7 then run the following command:

```sh
npm update @babel/core @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

or just upgrade Babel by following the [Babel v7 Migration Guide](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration)

Alternately, you can replace the empty tags with React Fragments like this:

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react"

// use it like this:
<Fragment>
  <Component />
</Fragment>
```

Comment: but it's giving me this error when i use empty tags:

Comment: Jest encountered an unexpected token
      This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

Comment: You need Babel v7.0.0-beta.31 and above for this to work. I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: You're welcome, I'm happy to help. If I could help answer your question, I'd appreciate if you can mark this answer as the "accepted" one by ticking the grey "Tick" to the left of my answer.